# Multiple lines in JList java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jlist

I'm currently working on a school project regarding school administration. In my project it is possible to create a school, education and students. I'm currently adding them all into the same JList(School), and it is giving me one problem. Whenever I'm adding for example a student it goes into the same line on the JList which makes it too long and I'm hoping for a way to do something like this on it:

School 1
  - Education 1
     - Student 1
     - Student 2
  - Education 2
     - Student 3
School 2
etc. 
etc.

I've been reading about using cell renderer but I'm not sure that it works since I'm not creating a table. Please advice me about what to use.

Regards
Jakob

Btw I don't want to use TextArea since I want to challenge myself.

Comment: "_I want to challenge myself._" Then why come here asking for us to help you?

Comment: I'm not asking anyone for giving me a piece of code but give me a direction to go?

Answer (score 3):

> "I've been reading about using cell renderer but I'm not sure that it works since I'm not creating a table. "

There are different renderers for different components. `JList` has one and so does a `JTabele` You need to use a `ListCellRender`, which is a renderer for a `JList` cell. The renderer uses a `Component` to contain its content. With `Component` you can't use the next line carriage "\n", so you need to use HTML.

You can see more here [**ListCellRenderer**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html)

Here's an example, where I use a Student Object as the value for the list

```
class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
    public Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

And here is the part of the render where I set the text

```
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index,
        boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    Student label = (Student) value;
    String name = label.getName();
    int age = label.getAge();
    String labelText = "<html>" + name + "<br/>" + age;
    setText(labelText);

    return this;
}
```

Here's the complete example

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Test3 {

    JList<Student> list;
    DefaultListModel model;

    public Test3() {
        list = new JList();
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            model.addElement(new Student("Paul" + i, i));
        }
        list.setModel(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(list);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Test3();
            }
        });
    }

    private class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            Student label = (Student) value;
            String name = label.getName();
            int age = label.getAge();
            String labelText = "<html>Name: " + name + "<br/>Age: " + age;
            setText(labelText);

            return this;
        }

    }
}

class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
    public Student(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the way we have been taught how to create objects.

Comment: This is the way we have been taught how to create objects.

public static void createAndStoreSomeObjects() {
School s1 = createSchool("School name1", "School adress 1");
School s2 = createSchool("School name2", "School adress 2");

Education e1 = s1.createEducation("Education1", s1);
Education e2 = s1.createEducation("Education2", s1);

Student stu1 = s1.createStudent("Student name1", "Students adress", "city", "zipcode", e1);
Student stu2 = s1.createStudent("Student name2", "Students adress", "city", "zipcode", e1);

Comment: Ok but what does that have to do with a Jlist? What I gave you is how to render a list cell using a simple `Student` object. Since you wanted the challenge, its your job to create the the cell renderer. I just gave you a blueprint to work with. You can look at the link above and also see [**How to use custom renderer**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more details

Comment: Yeah, I guess u are right. Thanks for taking time to help me :)