# Working with MouseEvents: Am I doing this correctly?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, mouselistener

I am very new to MouseEvents and MouseListeners, and I had recently asked a question about creating a basketball shot chart. What I have so far is this

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class StatTracker extends JPanel //implements MouseListener
{
   JPanel court;
   int xCoord, yCoord, clicks;
   boolean made, missed = false;
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      //Draw court lines
      g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g.fillRect(190,0,120,190);
      g.drawOval(190,130,120,120);
      g.drawRect(0,0,500,400);
      g.drawArc(52,-110,396,360,0,-180);
      g.drawLine(52,0,52,70);
      g.drawLine(448,0,448,70);

      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.fillRect(220,35,60,5);
      g.fillOval(240,40,20,20);
      if(made)
      {
         g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
         g.drawString("O", xCoord, yCoord);
      }
      if(missed)
      {
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.drawString("X", xCoord, yCoord);
      }
      //made=false;
      //missed=false;
   } 
   public StatTracker()
   { 
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      court = new JPanel();
   }
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
   {
      clicks = e.getClickCount();
      xCoord = e.getX();
      yCoord = e.getY();
      if(xCoord <=500 && xCoord >= 0)
      {
         if(clicks==1)
            missed=true;
         if(clicks==2)
            made=true;
      }
      repaint();
   }
}
```

So that basically if the mouse is clicked within the bounds of the court (0-500, 0-400), it will display an 'X' or 'O' based on if it was a single or double click. The main method is in a separate driver file and everything runs correctly (court appears on screen) but nothing occurs when I click on the court.

Any help or advice is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you commented out the `MouseListener` because you were getting an error.

The thing is, when you `implements MouseListener`, you need to `@Override` *all* the methods, not just `mouseClicked`

```
public class StatTracker extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

The ones you don't need you can just leave empty. Just add code to the `mouseClicked` if that's all you need.

Also you need to call `super.paintComponent(g)` in your `paintComponent` method

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

Also as you can see from my code, I use the @Override annotation. You should make a habit of doing this for methods you are attempting to override. If it is a successful override, you won't get an error. If it isn't then you will get an error.

Comment: nitpicking: don't widen the scope of paintComponent - it's meant for internal usage only :-)

Comment: @kleopatra it was a typo. It's late here. Almost time for bed :)

Comment: +1 happily granted .. given a certain amount of [second life in insomnia 3hrs later](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21502062/203657) <tongue-in-cheek-of-course/>

Comment: @kleopatra <head-down> Ok mom you caught me. But.. but.. it's the weekend :P